# "Every vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis" $\Leftrightarrow$ Axiom of choice?

Tags: vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

It is known that "every vector space has a basis" $\Leftrightarrow$ Axiom of choice

but do we have the same thing with a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: As a small note, you might be interested in learning that for any field $k$, "every vector space over a field extension of $k$ has a basis" $\implies$ AC.

Comment: Do you know a demonstration of what you claim (or maybe a link for the demonstration) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't. It was presented to me in a lecture. As far as I know, it follows immediately from the standard proof that the existence of bases implies AC.